# Switch doesn't work with numeric comparison cases

Tags: php

Here is my code.

```
$value = 0;
switch($value) {
      case ( $value <= 25 ):
            $CompScore = 'low';
            break;
      case ($value > 25 && $value <= 50 ):
            $CompScore = 'fair';
            break;
      case ($value > 50 && $value <= 75 ):
            $CompScore = 'good';
            break;
      case ($value >75 ):
            $CompScore = 'excellent';
            break;
      default:
            $CompScore = 'low';
            break;
}

echo $CompScore;
```

When the value is `0`, `$compScore` is `fair`. Why it is not showing `low`? I don't understand why.

Comment: This is not how switch blocks are used. The reason to use a switch, is to evaluate $value ONCE then check for qualifying case values.  Because you are performing separate evaluations on `$value`, you could write equally efficient code more concisely with an `if-elseif-else` block.  Best of all would be to use `isset()` with a lookup array, and assign a default value when the input does not fall in one of the expected groups.  (As demonstrated by my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you pass into a switch statement is basically what the switch statement looks for an evaluated match for, going from top to bottom down the list of cases until it finds one it is **equal** to (loose comparison), e.g. `true == true`.

In your example, your [comparisons](http://php.net/ternary) are evaluated as booleans (true or false) - your variable `$value` is set to zero, which is **equal** to `false`, but not **identical** (strict comparison) to `false`. For example:

```
(0 == false)    // true
(0 === false)   // false
(1 == false)    // false
(1 === false)   // false
(1 == true)     // true
(1 === true)    // false
(true === true) // true
```

So by using a boolean `true` as your switch value, you can do this to have **numeric comparison** inside the statement, where each comparison will evaluate to either `true` or `false` to match/not match the original `true` value (boolean - boolean comparison).

```
switch(true) {
       case ($value <= 25):                 // true
             $CompScore = 'low';
             break;
       case ($value > 25 && $value <= 50 ): // false
             $CompScore = 'fair';
             break;
       case ($value > 50 && $value <= 75 ): // false
             $CompScore = 'good';
             break;
       case ($value >75 ):                  // false
             $CompScore = 'excellent';
             break;
       default:                             // if you removed the first case
             $CompScore = 'low';            // this default case would be used
             break;                         
 }
```

Comment: Thought the question was " Why it is not showing low?"

Comment: Example does show low. Why was this down voted? Will delete if it's reasonable.

Comment: You don't explain WHY it's not working with the original code.

Answer (score 2):

`switch` not working like that.

Since `$value` is `0` which is falsy value.

`$value <= 25` is `true`, `$value > 25 && $value <= 50` is `false`, so `$CompScore` will be `'fair'`.

For you code, use an `if elseif else` flow will be more readable.

You could rewrite your code like below:

```
// from excellent to low
if ($value > 75) {
  $CompScore = 'excellent';
} else if ($value > 50) {
  $CompScore = 'good';
} else if ($value > 25) {
  $CompScore = 'fair';
} else {
  $CompScore = 'low';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you use your switch in a particular way.

You are saying :

```
$value = 0;
Switch ($value){
    case ($value < 25):
        ....

}
```

This finally compares $value<25 and 0 as described below :

```
($value<25) == $value.
=> true == 0
```

Which is wrong because `true != 0`

A way to do what you want this way is simply to replace `switch($value)` with `switch(true)` so the interpreter will actually compare check if your case statements are true.

Answer (score 0):

You can "smarten up" your code with a lookup array and some simple mathematics.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bQLQG))

```
$lookup = [
    1 => 'low',
    2 => 'fair',
    3 => 'good',
    4 => 'excellent'
];

for ($i = -1; $i <= 101; ++$i) {
    echo "\n$i : " , $lookup[ceil($i / 25)] ?? $lookup[1];
}
```

By dividing the value by 25, then rounding up to the next whole number (with `ceil()`), you achieve the same result without a battery of condition statements.  Using a lookup away not only keeps your code compact, it ensures that you aren't performing *n* checks on the same value AND it provides a clean separation between the process and the values.

If you ever decide to split the groups by 20, instead of 25, you would only need to change the `25` to `20`, then add a fifth lookup value in the desired location (with the appropriate key).