# The switch-case failing

Tags: php

I have a function like this:

```
public static function GetNilaiHuruf($nilai)
{
  if($nilai > 4)
  {
    $nilai = (float) ((float)($nilai) / (float)(100.0) * (float)4.0);
  }

  switch($nilai)
  {
    case ($nilai > 3.66 && $nilai <= 4) :
      return "A";
      break;
    case ($nilai > 3.33 && $nilai <= 3.66) :
      return "A-";
      break;
    case ($nilai > 3.00 && $nilai <= 3.33) :
      return 'B+';
      break;
    case ($nilai > 2.66 && $nilai <= 3.00) :
      return 'B';
      break;
    case ($nilai > 2.33 && $nilai <= 2.66) :
      return 'B-';
      break;
    case ($nilai > 2.00 && $nilai <= 2.33) :
      return 'C+';
      break;
    case ($nilai > 1.66 && $nilai <= 2.00) :
      return 'C';
      break;
    case ($nilai > 1.33 && $nilai <= 1.66) :
      return 'C-';
      break;
    case ($nilai > 1.00 && $nilai <= 1.33) :
      return 'D+';
      break;
    case ($nilai >= 0.00 && $nilai <= 1.00) :
      return 'D';
      break;
  }
}
```

When I call that function with $nilai is 0, the function returns 'A';
When I call that function with $nilai is 0.007 or 'x', the function returns 'D'.

How is that possible?

Comment: isnt this `if($nilai > 4)` should be `if($nilai <=4)` ?

Comment: no, there are values that ranges from 0-100 that need to be converted to ranges from 0-4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how switch statements work, they shouldn't be used to do numeric comparisons like that.

However, you *can* achieve what you want by using boolean true as your switch argument:

```
$yourvar = -20;

switch(true) {
    case ($yourvar > 0 && $yourvar < 5) :
        echo 'Hello world!';
        break;
    case ($yourvar < 0) : 
        echo 'Hello hell!';
        break;
}

// Hello hell!
```

[Please see this article for more info.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22214585/2812842)

Comment: I see... let me try that..

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to try to use a `switch` here. Use `if`/`else if`/`else`:

```
if ($nilai > 3.66 && $nilai <= 4) {
    return "A";
} else if ($nilai > 3.33 && $nilai <= 3.66) {
    return "A-";
} ...
```